# Reach out to MAMP

Tags: support, outsourcing

MAMP/MAMP PRO is linking to Stack Overflow [from their support page](https://www.mamp.info/en/support/) without any qualifiers, which led to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721467/mamp-pro-update-the-update-could-not-be-validated). Perhaps someone should reach out to them and ask them to tell their users what kind of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: I've deleted my question, -5 downvote is enough for me. I will try to reach MAMP PRO about this link to SO.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel If you hear back from them, please submit an answer here. I'm not the only one who will be promising you a +1

Comment: There are several other questions that should be directed at MAMP support, I commented some of them.

Comment: In case anyone's not familiar, the official help page to point MAMP to is this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: why not burninating [mamp*] tags? their filter would be moot at least.

Comment: @Jean There's nothing wrong with [tag:mamp] per se, it's a pretty commonly used tool.

Comment: Same happens for Aerospike https://www.aerospike.com/community/

Comment: @web Post a new question so somebody from the community team can take a look.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The only off-topic MAMP/WAMP questions involve installation. Those should be pointed to [Super User](//superuser.com). Otherwise, they're considered programming tools

Comment: It's on our radar; we'll reach out ;)

Comment: The link to Stack Overflow on MAMP PRO support page is removed : https://www.mamp.info/en/support/

Answer (score 6):

I explained the problem to MAMP Pro support. Here is their answer :

> We will be removing the link to stackOverflow. We are going to answer
>   what we can through zendesk.

Comment: Hmmm. Oh well. I am not against MAMP questions; their reaction feels a bit drastic, but it's better than having people dropped on SO without further guidance. Thanks for your efforts here!